# How to consume a Swift framework or library from OS X Command Line Tool

Tags: swift, macos, command-line, frameworks

I'm working on a project in Swift and I have a chunk of logic that I'd like to put in a framework/library so that I can easily test it, consume it in a OS X command line tool, and eventually consume it in a OS X GUI app.

I'm using Xcode 7.2/Swift 2.1

Unless this has changed recently you can't make a static library containing Swift, so a dynamic framework is the only option. The problem is that the OS X Command Line Tool template doesn't have the General tab for the CLI target so the normal link/embed framework workflow doesn't work. How can I consume this framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to find [a blog](http://colemancda.github.io/2015/02/12/embedded-swift-frameworks-osx-command-line-tools) that lists exactly how to do this. The downside is that the resultant build products are a bundle (the instructions also work if you replace bundle with GUI app), with the command line tool's executable in the bundle/app's `Contents/MacOS` folder. So the user can not just call `./BundleName.bundle` or `./AppName.app` and have the command line tool run, they have to do `./BundleName.bundle/Contents/MacOS/CommandLineTool`.

I'm hesitant to actually use a bundle as I feel most people will not understand what to do with it, and since it's the same effort to embed in a GUI app that's the route I'm leaning towards. Currently I won't be adding any functionality to the app, but I could at least add a label to show usage instructions for the command line tool.

The only other option I've found is to make the framework like normal, but also set the target membership of all the framework's Swift files to also include them in the command line tool's target. This will make the command line tool have all the files it needs to work, and prevent any bundle/app nesting. This is closer to my original ideal result.

Comment: Can you expand on your third paragraph "The only other option I've found is to make the framework like normal..." What do you mean by "the framework"?

Comment: Basically I would have 2 targets in my project. An macOS Framework target, and an macOS CLI app. The way to use code in both (if you choose this option), is to select each code file and check it's target membership check boxes so that it's included in both the framework and CLI targets.